# Error CS0103 The name 'Image' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

the "Image" part from the Image.FromFile says it isnt in the right context:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Good.jfif");
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        clicker = new AutoClicker();
        LoadSettings();
        ClickTypeHandler(null, null);
        LocationHandler(null, null);
        DelayHandler(null, null);
        CountHandler(null, null);

        clicker.NextClick += HandleNextClick;
        clicker.Finished += HandleFinished;
    }
```

Comment: My guess is you are missing a using System.Drawing

Answer (score 1):

The `Image` class belongs to the namespace `System.Drawing`, thus you need to import it by using `using`, like this:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

This has the effect of putting all classes belonging to that namespace in the global scope, so that you can use `Image` directly.

Without `using`, you would have to use the full name (`System.Drawing.Image`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a namespace(at the keyboard try to click `CTRL` + `.`) :

```
using System.Drawing

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Good.jfif");
    this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    clicker = new AutoClicker();
    LoadSettings();
    ClickTypeHandler(null, null);
    LocationHandler(null, null);
    DelayHandler(null, null);
    CountHandler(null, null);

    clicker.NextClick += HandleNextClick;
    clicker.Finished += HandleFinished;
}
```

As a compilator does not know where to get methods for `Image` class. The compilator ought to know where to get the method and what result should return this method before program is run. It means that C# is statically typed language.

[MSDN article about `Image.FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.7.2)